# Ошибка в создании БД через дискорд бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3, discord.py

При использовании данного куска кода, бот создает БД

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@slash.subcommand(base='db', name='make', description='Command to make the database for user notes.', guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def make(ctx):
    database = sqlite3.connect('user_notes.db')
    c = database.cursor()
    c.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE user_notes (user_ids text, usernames text, notes text, friend_code text, sex)''')
    database.commit()
    database.close()
    await ctx.send('Database has been created!', hidden=True)
    channel = discord.utils.get(Client.get_all_channels(), name='general')
    await channel.send("Bot is back up!")
```

но возникает данная ошибка

> line 68, in make
> channel = discord.utils.get(Client.get_all_channels(), name='general')
> TypeError: get_all_channels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

БД создается, можно вводить данные в нее через бота, бот продолжает работать, но читать и выводить бот данные не может, как исправить?

используемые библиотеки -

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Client, Intents
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
import sqlite3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import datetime
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
```

Comment: Покажи больше кода

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, чтобы ее решить я просто за вместо **Client** указал переменную экземпляра бота , т.е. **noter**.